# Cypress - wait for button to be clickable

Tags: cypress

I know it works most of the time, but on a web page I tested, on following line

```
cy.get('button[title="Query"]').click()
```

Cypress runner passed `get` but hung on the `click` action till timeout. If I modify the code to

```
cy.get('button[title="Query"]').as('query')
cy.wait(500)
cy.get('@query').click()
```

The test succeeds.

Obviously arbitrary wait is a bad practice. Automatic waiting, retry-ability - as claimed by Cypress as features, are suppose to prevent above scenario from happening but failed in my case.

Furthermore, Cypress has no `should('be.clickable')` assertion. How could I instruct Cypress to wait for a button to be clickable before clicking it, or if clicking hung, then retry with a interval until success?

Comment: Hi. Did you try to use the options from the click command (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Arguments)?
e.g. click({ timeout: 10000 })

Comment: No, but I changed defaultCommandTimeout globally to 60s.

Comment: Tried timeout option just now. No effect.

Comment: did you try `should('be.visible')`?

Comment: I got it working and posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be caused by race condition between cypress script and app code **before** `cy.get` in a way that, at the time of clicking, the app page state is still in transition such that the button is visible and enabled but the intended event listener hasn't been attached to the button yet. It is more likely so if following code also works

```js
cy.wait(500).get('button[title="Query"]').click()
```

A better alternative than waiting for arbitrary length is to add assertions for other DOM elements to make sure button is in a click-ready state. In my case, the button is in a tab. I clicked the tab before clicking the button. So make sure the tab is selected and elements in the tab are rendered first

```js
cy.get('li[aria-label="Service Selected"]')
cy.get('table.xxx thead tr :nth-child(3)').should('include.text', 'foo')
cy.get('button[title="Query"]').click()
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that the button is not clickable, it's getting stuck in the click handler.

Every `<button>` element has a click handler by default. For instance a very simple page

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

running this

```
it('shows the click handler', () => {
  cy.visit('../app/clickable.html')
  
  cy.get('button')
    .then($button => {
      console.log($button[0].click)
    })
    .click()
})
```

logs this

```
ƒ click() { [native code] }
```

Even if the click handler is removed, it doesn't hang or error

```
<button id="thebutton">Click me</button>
<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('thebutton')
  button.click = undefined;
</script>
```

logs this

```
undefined
```

but does not error.

You need to find out what's happening in the click handler to cause the hang.

Comment: If stuck happens in click handler, it doesn't explain why click handler doesn't hang if called after 500ms as shown in 2nd code snippet

Comment: Well, the implication is something needs to complete (maybe a fetch) before the click handler can work.

Answer (score 0):

It is frustrating to use cy.wait() on a hanging button and hardcode wait seconds. There has to be a solution where Cypress sees the button no longer greyed out and continues the test.
This was my solution:
I used an if statement:

```
cy.waitForStableDOM //this is a plug-in that helps to be sure your DOM is stable
if(cy.get('your element/button').should('be.disabled'))
{
   cy.get('your element/button').wait(6000).click({force:true})
} 
else if(cy.get('your element/button').should('be.not.disabled'))
{
   cy.get('your element/button').click({force:true})
}
```

Maybe this may help, BTW the [waitForStableDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-for-stable-dom) is a [Mutation Observer](https://medium.com/tailwind-culture/what-is-a-mutation-observer-and-when-should-you-use-it-df134aabe516). This is a great tool when waiting for Elements to load.
Hope this helps.